# Populate Selectize Dropdown from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the Selectize jQuery plugin and would like to populate the dropdown box with the results of a PHP output.  I am able to get the data in the box, but there are multiple options and it is putting them all on one line instead of separate options.  Any ideas?

jQuery

```
$("#SearchForm_1").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), 
           $(this).serialize(),
           function(data) {
                var selectize_tags = $("#GameDetails_1")[0].selectize;
                selectize_tags.addOption({
                    text:data,
                    value: data
                });
                selectize_tags.addItem(data);
        });
    );
});

$('#GameDetails_1').selectize({
    selectOnTab:true
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="control-group">         
    <select id="GameDetails_1" name="GameDetails_1" autocomplete="false">

    </select>
</div>
```

PHP Output

```
echo $query_result['GameTitle'];
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple ?

```
<div class="control-group">         
    <select id="GameDetails_1" name="GameDetails_1" autocomplete="false">
         <?php echo '<option value="">' . $query_result['GameTitle'] . '</option>'; ?> 
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The php result is coming from a separate file on a form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Selectize jQuery plugin](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/), and fetching records from database via Ajax.

and PHP output you are trying is `echo $query_result['GameTitle'];` which only obiviously print the result in one line, what you need is to put the `$query_result['GameTitle']` inside the `<option></option>` tags to pupulate the  element

so the PHP Output will be

```
echo "<option value='".$query_result['GameTitle']."'>".$query_result['GameTitle']."</option>";
```

and will populate `<option></option>` tags inside `select` element

```
<div class="control-group">         
    <select id="GameDetails_1" name="GameDetails_1" autocomplete="false">

    </select>
</div>
```